# Sms not arriving in the "SM" storage on ZTE MF667

Tags: c#, serial-port, at-command, modem

I was trying to setup the "SM" storage for my ZTE MF667 modem and i encountered the serious problem, the messages do not pass to the "SM" storage, instead they always fall into the "ME" memory which i cant read on this modem using at commands (it's always flushed to zero).

My setup looks like so:

```
 port= new SerialPort(com);
 port.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;
 port.NewLine = System.Environment.NewLine;
 port.ReadTimeout = ReadTimeout;
 port.WriteTimeout = -1;
 this.AddCallbacks();  
 port.Open();


 port.Write("AT+ZSNT=0,0,0\r\n");
 Console.WriteLine(this.GetTheResult());  //print the output
 port.Write("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
 Console.WriteLine(this.GetTheResult());  //print the output
 port.Write(@"AT+CPMS=""SM"",""SM"",""SM""\r\n");
 Console.WriteLine(this.GetTheResult());  //print the output
 port.Write("AT+CNMI=2,1,0,0,0\r\n");
 Console.WriteLine(this.GetTheResult());  //print the output  
 port.Write(@"AT+CUSD=1,""*102#"",15\r\n");
 Console.WriteLine(this.GetTheResult());  //print the output
```

Here im sending the ussd, and i'm getting the result message, that i will be notified trough sms message.

```
+CMTI: "ME",0
```

The problem is, for some reason the message is arriving in "ME" storage, and i cannot read it using `AT+CMGL` or `AT+CMGR`. I do not know if it is the whole ZTE MF problem, or just ZTE MF667 problem. Can someone help me, what i need to do to make this work?

P.S.

The result of `AT&V`

```
Recieve: &C: 1; &D: 2; &E: 0; &F: 0; &S: 0; &W: 0; E: 1; L: 0; M: 0; Q: 0; V: 1;
Recieve: X: 1; Z: 0; \Q: 3; \S: 0; \V: 1; O: 0; S0: 0; S2: 43; S3: 13; S4: 10;
Recieve: S5: 8; S6: 2; S7: 50; S8: 2; S9: 6; S10: 14; S11: 95; S30: 0; S103: 1;
Recieve: S104: 1; +FCLASS: 0; +ICF: 3,3; +IFC: 2,2; +IPR: 115200; +DR: 0;
Recieve: +DS: 0,0,2048,6; +CMEE: 2; +WS46: 12; +CBST: 0,0,1;
Recieve: +CRLP: (61,61,48,6,0),(61,61,48,6,1),(240,240,52,6,2);
Recieve: +CV120: 1,1,1,0,0,0; +CHSN: 0,0,0,0; +CSSN: 0,0; +CREG: 0; +CGREG: 0;
Recieve: +CFUN:; +CSCS: "IRA"; +CSTA: 129; +CR: 0; +CRC: 0; +CGDCONT: (1,"IP","","0.0.0.0",0,0)
Recieve: ; +CGDSCONT: ; +CGTFT: ; +CGEQREQ: ; +CGEQMIN: ; +CGQREQ: ; +CGQMIN: ;
Recieve: +CGEREP: 0,0; +CGDATA: "PPP"; +CGCLASS: "A"; +CGSMS: 1; +CSMS: 0;
Recieve: +CMGF: 1; +CSAS: 0; +CRES: 0; +CSCA: "+7913454111",145; +CSMP: ,,0,0;
Recieve: +CSDH: 0; +CSCB: 0,"",""; +FDD: 0; +FAR: 0; +FCL: 0; +FIT: 0,0; +ES: ,,;
Recieve: +ESA: 0,,,,0,0,255,; +CMOD: 0; +CVHU: 1; +CPIN: ????????,????????;
Recieve: +CMEC: 0,0,0,0; +CIND: 0,2,1,0,0,0,1,0; +CMER: 0,0,0,0,0; +CGATT: 1;
Recieve: +CGACT: 0; +CPBS: "SM"; +CPMS: "SM","SM","SM"; +CNMI: 2,1,0,0,0;
Recieve: +CMMS: 0;  +FTS: 0; +FRS: 0; +FTH: 3; +FRH: 3; +FTM: 96; +FRM: 96;
Recieve: +CCUG: 0,0,0; +COPS: 0,0,""; +CUSD: 1; +CAOC: 1; +CCWA: 1; +CCLK: "";
Recieve: +CPOL: 0,2,"",0,0,0; +CPLS: 0; +CTZR: 0; +CTZU: 0; +CLIP: 1; +COLP: 0;
Recieve: +CDIP: 0; +CLIR: 0; +VTS: 0; +ZSNT: 0,0,0; ; +ZOPRT: 0; +ZCIN: "",,;
Recieve: +ZDLFREQ: 0,0; +ZSNT: 0,0,0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AT+CPMS?
+CPMS: "MT",0,100,"ME",0,100,"ME",0,100

OK
AT+CPMS=?
+CPMS: ("ME","MT","SM","SR"),("ME","MT","SM","SR"),("ME","MT","SM","SR")

OK
AT+CPMS="ME","ME","ME"
+CPMS: 0,100,0,100,0,100

OK
AT+CPMS="SM","SM","SM"
+CPMS: 0,15,0,15,0,15


+CMTI: SM,0
AT+CMGL="ALL"
+CMGL: 0,"REC UNREAD","0200003903100320360",,"15/05/29,23:14:00+20"
00234324234324324234
```

WORKS!